# how to set a form field with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Hi i have this html code which shows an input field:

```
<div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
                <div id="#wijzig">
                    <h3>Uw e-mail adres</h3>

                    <p>
                        <input type="button" onclick="$(this).closest('.ui-btn').hide(); $('form').show();" value="Wijzig mijn e-mailadres" />
                    </p>


                    <form action="javascript:getUpdateValues();" method="post" style="display:none;">
                        <div class="ui-grid-a">
                            <div class="ui-block-a">E-Mail: <input type="text" id="email" name="email" style = "margin-top: .6em; padding-right: 0px"  /></div>
                            <div class="ui-block-b" style="width: 100px;"><br/><input type="submit" value="Wijzig" /></div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
              </div>
            </div>
```

What i want to do is that if this input field is shown that it also shows the existing user email, which comes from JSON:

```
var myData = [
                  {"Email":"asdads@asd.com","Wachtwoord":"blabla"}
                  ];



        $.each(myData, function(index, element) {

           $("#email").val(element.Email);


           });
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work i.e the input field won't contain the email from the hardcoded JSON, any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$("#email").append(element.Email);` is wrong if you want to set the value to the input box, you should

```
$("#email").val(element.Email);
```

> .val( value ) - Set the value of each element in the set of matched
>   elements.

[Read more here about .val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

***[Try the demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/PqTJX/)***

if you come across any problem let me know. Hope this will fix your problem.

Comment: yes i see it works there, thats strange because it wont here,, im using Phonegap by the way.. maybe thats the issue

Comment: check the JS section of your browser and post if you have any errors there

Comment: yep works... There was another problem why it didn't work.. there was a mistake in the html thats why.

Answer (score 0):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/6JZ6E/

http://api.jquery.com/val/ ==> `$("#email").val(element.Email);`

rest should fit the need `:)`

**code**

```
var myData = [
    {
    "Email": "nuri@ensing",
    "Wachtwoord": "blabla"}
];



$.each(myData, function(index, element) {
alert(element.Email);
    $("#email").val(element.Email);


});​
```